# Forbid access to config var in Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

One of the config vars in my Heroku app holds a key which not all members of team should have access to, but I need few of them to keep operating the app. I understand there is a Heroku Enterprise plan but by not assigning the "operator" nor the "deployer" role means they cannot continue operating the app, which is pointless. I would love to Heroku to have access permissions based on attributes not roles in a manner that I could only forbid access to a config var (or vars).

1. Do you think this is possible?
2. If not, which other provider offers what I'm looking for?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, and would be quite difficult to make possible.

Even if your developer didn't have the right to see some config vars, as soon as they have the "deployer" right, your developers can run a one-off dyno.

Then, it's very easy to do: `heroku run bash` and simply output the variable.

Comment: Yes, I did a lot of thinking and came to same conclusion. Makes sense Heroku designed it that way. Thanks.